# Xampp: web browser won't show the localhost page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I have installed xampp on Windows7(64bit).I want to work with PHP, Apache and MySql.
The server Apache and the MySql services are running properly on the Xampp control panel.
But when I run the localhost on my web browser it just shows connecting. Nothing else. Compare to previous enviroment it runs well with IIS.

Comment: What browser are you trying this in? Have you tried typing in 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Try running apache_start.bat from the cmd line and it should show you some error messages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing a netstat -a on your cmd and see if there are any other services which are running on port 80.You can also use netstat -b to find the name of the service however this requires cmd to be run as administrator.  The most likely culprit is that there are some other services running on this port which do not allow Xampp to start up properly? Do you  have a service like skype . If so that is the reason your not able to access particular page. An other thing you can do is to go into httpd.conf and change the listen to some other port other than 80 and test it out.Dont forget to add `localhost:your selected port` once you change the port to test it out.

Comment: If it is skype, go into Skype > Tools > Options > Advanced > Connections and remove the tick that says use port 80 and 443

Comment: Yeap. Hate you skype, the first time i encountered this issue i had to view windows log to see why the apache did not start

Answer (score 7):

If you changed your port number, then type localhost:'port number' to get to the xampp page.

ex: If your port number is 8080, then type `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible that IIS or any other program (like Skype) causes Apache not to start. Although it shows "running" its actually not running.

To solve this, there is an easy trick: Install Apache as an service and restart your computer. This wil work most of the time, since there are a lot of programs that reserve port 80 its hard to find these programs and disable them.

Answer (score 1):

if it's not the port, then go to htdocs, delete dashboard file and index file and you are good to go! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your apache listining port from 80 to 8080 ,then . . . write 
localhost:8080/your_URL ... it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have following errors: 
*[Wed Jun 10 10:32:13.697671 2015] [core:warn] [pid 1408:tid 248] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20060613/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.sote does NOT include an ID which matches the server name*

which i am extracted from  Apache Error log file.

Then you need check for running process of apache, you can do command also or you can do using GUI.  I am explaining GUI method, open task manager(using ctrl+shift+esc) and  go into process list and be assure that all the processes are visible including other logged in users. And search for Apache process and end them . You are done run it using XAmpp or wamp control panel.