# Connecting to Localhost [Different Path]

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed Xampp 1.8.2 yesterday, and installed Apache and MySQL modules and they are running fine in  the control panel, there was no issue here:

[image]

After I click the admin button, It should direct me to the 'localhost page' but I have a different path instead of localhost it opens a different IP: `http://130.147.134.177/xampp/`

[image]

It should open like this:

[image]

I have tried clicking the `https://localhost` link and the `https://127.0.0.1` link in the img shown but after clicking the link there is a blank page which says:

[image]

and Whenever I open a page connected to the localhost it directs me to the `http://130.147.134.177/xampp/` page not showing the result.

How can I change the path back to localhost so I can easily open my files and easily work on my php files? I have a file called fileupload.php. I enter the following path `localhost/fileupload.php` but it directs me to the `http://130.147.134.177/xampp/` page.

What should I do to fix this. I tried configuring my httpd-xampp.conf file. But still doesn't work. My head is killing me!

my netstat results: [image]

There seems to be another error restricting me to use Xampp anymore:

[image]

Comment: Open the file apache/conf/httpd.conf.
Search for "30.147.134.177" . If it is there, then change it to `Listen 80`

Comment: #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80 This is what it shows.

It is listening to Port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the "phpMyAdmin" under Tools in your second image. And it will redirect you to a url "localhost/xampp/". Hope this helps.

Comment: I have clicked the phpmyadmin page this is the path it directs to: http://130.147.134.177/phpmyadmin/#PMAURL-0:index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=f0271a958a2ae0ef2bcfbf7afeee126a

Comment: where did you install or the location of your xampp?

Comment: C:\xampp. C: drive is my System drive.

Comment: Where did you save your fileupload.php?

Comment: try to going here bro :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020804/xampp-web-browser-wont-show-the-localhost-page

Comment: There is no problem with the port conflicts I was reading the same article yesterday but didn't help me. Apache is opening the xampp page meaning it is working but not with Localhost. My netstat results are shown in the image

Comment: Try stopping IIS. 

Select Start, then type IIS in the search box
select Internet Information Services Manager
In the manager on the right under "Manage server"select "stop"

Comment: OR ELSE Have you got any kind of firewall?

If so, deactivate it and try again.

Comment: OR ELSE click on the Config at the left side of your xampp and check on the ports of mysql and other tab there.

Comment: Apache2.4 - 80 [Main Port] 
443 [SSL Port]

mysql - 3306 


There are the ports being used by the services. Firstly, there is no IIS in my computer I don't seem to have Internet Information Services Manager". Secondly, I turned off my Firewall and it didn't work. Lastly i check all the ports no port conflicts nor issues with the port.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44868/discussion-between-jay-and-aljie)

Answer (score 0):

Try Editing the Apache Config File.

By Clicking the Apache config button in the Xampp control panel, you will get(Appache(httpd.config)) file.

In that file, search for "Listen 85" and Edit the "Listen 85" to "Listen 80".

Save the File and Close.

And then Stop all the actions. Wait for few seconds. Start the Actions now.

It will Work...

Comment: #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

ServerName localhost:80

It is not Listening to port 85 as port 80 is the default port. It is listening to port 80

Comment: Do you have these lines in the httpd.config file "#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80"

Comment: Yes I have the following lines: "#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 80" in the httpd.conf file. As i have stated already.

Comment: change the "#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 80" into "#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080 Listen 8080". save it. stop all actions. restart the actions. Open browser and then type localhost:8080/ and enter.

Comment: Nope, I tried changing it from port 80 to port 8080. Changed both the lines, it doesn't work. I am having this error:

Request Error (invalid_request) 

Your request could not be processed.
This could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed request.

For assistance, contact your network support team.

Comment: is there any lines like this `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in the httpd.config file.

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact There is a statement. # Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: what is the version of the Xampp using...?

Comment: I am using XAMPP 1.8.2 in Windows.

Comment: try downloading a new copy of xampp v1.8.2 and make a clean install.

Comment: I just downloaded the same version, installed it like 3 times already. Sadly, it doesn't work.