# Xampp localhost not working and showing a blank page?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

So I installed xampp and tried to start but Apache was giving the usual error of port busy and I changed the port address to 8080 and also the localhost to 8080 in the httpd.conf file.

Now,localhost just shows a blank page,no files I save in the htdocs folder show up.It's just a blank page and nothing happens.Any suggestions?

Comment: Were there still errors after changing the port to 8080, or were you able to start apache? Also, did you enter 'localhost' or 'localhost:8080' in the browser?

Comment: please test your port. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960750/how-to-find-which-program-is-using-port-80-in-windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xampp: web browser won't show the localhost page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020804/xampp-web-browser-wont-show-the-localhost-page)

Comment: Actually I just uninstalled it and then installed again,I had to change the port address again in the httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Try: "localhost:8080" instead of "localhost" in URL area.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Already Face This issue. First Of All Save Your File Like First.php And Then Run .And keep In Mind Do Not Keep File Name Index.php

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).